# Is it possible for Ubuntu 12:10 to re-install my lost Windows 7 Home 64-bit,? If possible which are all the steps to do it?

Tags: windows

I have no Ubuntu experience, I did install Ubuntu 12:10 recently cause I have read and overheard that Ubuntu could fix my Windows 7 64-bit re-installation. This is my last recourse. I have tried a few things already with windows with no success.

- I have a Dell Desktop which came with NO Full Windows 7 Home 64-bit disk.
  Dell provides users with what they call a "re-Installation Disk of the OS already installed in your computer original HDD".
- I also made "Rescue Disks #1 and #2" as per their suggestion.
- I downloads an ISO image of the windows 7 version i own. I also have the key code of my Windows activation with Microsoft

I have tried to re-install with the Dell Data Safe, I tried reinstalling following detailed instructions both from Seven Forums community as well as Microsoft Forums.

Nothing worked.

Aside from the SSD which i had the Win OS installed and now also has Ubuntu 12:10 I also own another 7 HDDs of different sizes and Brands.

I had the OS installed in more than just the SSD, in fact of all 8 disks only one boots Windows although after bypassing a boot error message.

All I want to do know is to recover (or reinstall) Win on the SSD

So my last 2 recourses left for me (ao so i think) are. 
a. Use ubuntu to recover (if possible) and
b. use the files still existent on the Recovery partition on the HDD that still boots to make a clean copy of a booting Windows 7 on the SSD/

Could anyone help me with my situation?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

As a straightforward solution and if you want to keep an Ubuntu installed, I suggest the following:

- use the windows iso together with the licensing key you have, burn it
  to a dvd and install as usual on your ssd... leave some room for
  ubuntu though (10-15gig would be sufficent to play a bit with it now
  and then)
- use the ubuntu live cd to install Ubuntu on the empty space. at the
  end of the installation ubuntu should take care of installing a
  bootloader and giving you the option to either startup windows or
  linux
- if using dell's recovery dvd it might be possible that it creates a checksum of your system and if something did change hardware wise, won't install because of licensing issues
- additionally: you can always use a ubuntu live cd to access data of a windows installation that doesn't boot anymore, if you didn't
  choose to use BitLocker encryption.. after bootup of the live cd you 
  should be able to browse through your "windows data" by just clicking
  on the partition you installed it to in the file browser

hope this helps!